# Dynamically expand jQuery UI buttonset to fill parent div

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI's buttonset() to create a naviagation/tab bar inside  tags.

```
<section id="menu-container" class="container">
    <nav id="group-menu" class="menu" data-bind="template: &#39;menuGroupTemplate&#39;">
        <div id="menu1">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Summary</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Category 1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Category 2</label>                    
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

The issue I'm having is that I need to have the nav bar stretch across the entire nav section that it is contained in.

The navigation data is potentially dynamic, so static padding won't be sufficient.

I attempted a function that padded out elements proportionally, but as I wrote it I noticed that `width()` and `outerWidth()` didn't seem to be reporting the same widths as I was seeing in my browser (chrome), and so I couldn't get the padding anywhere near correct!

```
function layoutMenuBar() {
    var childNodes = parent.children().find('span');
    var childCount = childNodes.length;

    var sumWidth = 0;
    childNodes.each(function() {
        sumWidth = sumWidth + parseInt($(this).outerWidth());
    });

    var parentWidth = parseInt(parent.outerWidth());
    var padding = parentWidth - sumWidth;

    if (padding > 0) {
        var newSumWidth = 0;

        childNodes.each(function() {
            var elemWidth = parseInt($(this).outerWidth());
            var elemPad = parseInt(elemWidth / sumWidth * padding / 2);

            $(this).css('padding-left', elemPad);
            $(this).css('padding-right', elemPad);
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this, or explain what would be going wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the `display` attribute, in particular with regards to tables.

You can layout each checkbox equally (in width) into the width you specify for the `nav` element:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#menu1 {
    display: table-row;
}

#menu1 > label {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/FZC4q/3/.